# Opensearch Dashboards - How to create a custom plugin/widget?

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

Is there a template or tutorial on creating a custom widget/template for opensearch dashboards? I have not been able to find any documentation on it, only for Opensearch itself. I am trying to create a custom plugin that will allow the ability to view images with the function of pan/zoom inside a dashboard widget. Any useful information or tips would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using the existing widgets to accomplish the use case but have not been able to. I also tried to look for resources related to custom plugins for Kibana since dashboards is built ontop of it but have had no success.

Comment: I'm being stacked at the same problem. The best artickle that I've found is this one - https://opensearch.org/blog/dashboards-plugins-intro/. But there is no explanation on what components do you need to use to make you own / changes to a visualization.